How can Nifi recognize a record in my database?
Note: I am still learning/new with apache nifi. I have created dataflows before and I am creating real-world scenario's to see how effective this tool is and if it can be a plug-in technology.
High-level Scenario:
I have a table in oracle full of employees [current and previous]. I want NiFi to ingest data from my email and as it is going through the extraction/transformation process to look in my tables to see if this is a new or previous employee.

If it is a new employee, kick that person to a holding queue for
review.

If it is a previous employee continue on with the current dataflow.


Do you think this is possible using NiFi? If so, where should I start with building this out?

Take a look at LookupAttribute and/or LookupRecord, using SimpleDatabaseLookupService or DatabaseRecordLookupService respectively. You should be able to route those employees not matched in the database to a different relationship downstream.
